Proof of a particular mapping of a compact set is compact
In PDE solving, especially in the Petrov-Galerkin Method, "compact support" is frequently mentioned, and I wanted to take the transformation from a stand triangle to the standard square on $[0,1]^2$ as an example:

If a function $f$ has compact support on a standard triangle $\Omega$, and using the transformation:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&x = uv \\
&y = u(1 - v)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Prove the function $f$ still has compact support on the transformed standard square area $\Omega'$.

Intuitively speaking, $f$ seems to have compact support on $\Omega'$. Then I need to prove:

The mapping is continuous (so that the image is still compact).
Points in $\Omega$ are still in $\Omega'$ $\Rightarrow$ Prove that the mapping is a bijection.

The definition "compact" requires the $\Omega$ is a closed set, which means the function supports both inside and on the boundary of $\Omega'$. Inside $\Omega$, I can prove the mapping is a bijection. But on the boundary, especially at the $(0,0)$ point ($x=y=0 \Rightarrow u=0, \forall v\in [0,1]$), the mapping is obviously not a bijection.
My question is,

Is the content I proposed to prove correct?
Do I need to prove the boundedness (the bijection on the boundary in the context) when proving the compactness?


When you take a sequence of points in a compact set since the set is bounded and closed. By Weierstrass the sequence has a  convergent subsequence.
use the transformation to another compact set on the sequence defined and you will get another bounded sequence.
Hence the transformation is compact.
This is the equivalent definition in metric spaces.

Thanks for answering my question! But your answer is still a bit abstract, so it took me a while to understand it. Do you mean that through the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, I just need to prove the transformed sequence is bounded, and the transformation is closed and continuous?
In my understanding, to prove the function $f$ still has compact support on $\Omega'$, I need to show the:

Continuity of the transformation
Boundedness of the sequence
Closedness of the image

